# Trouble mounting volume in docker within Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, flyway

I'm running flyway within my Jenkins pipeline. The docker image works and flyway runs fine. I can call `flyway baseline` to initialize the schema and that's about as far as I can get.

I'm attempting to mount the directory "Database/migrations" in the docker image using `image.withRun('-v /Database/migrations:/migrations'...` as listed in the segment below, but I'm not having any luck.

```
// git clone
stage("Checkout") {
    checkout scm
}

// db migration
stage('Apply DB changes') {
    sh "ls Database/migrations"
    def flyway = docker.image('flyway/flyway')
    flyway.withRun('-v /Database/migrations:/migrations', 
        '-url=jdbc:mysql://****:3306/**** -user=**** -password=**** -X -locations="filesystem:/migrations" migrate') { c ->
        sh "docker exec ${c.id} ls flyway"
        sh "docker logs --follow ${c.id}"
    }
}
```

Below is the debug from Jenkins for that stage (cleaned up for simplicity) and notice there is nothing under "migrations".

```
[Pipeline] { (Apply DB changes)
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls Database/migrations
V2__create_temp_table.sql
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker run -d -v /Database/migrations:/migrations flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:mysql://****:3306/**** -user=**** '-password=****' -X -locations=filesystem:/migrations migrate
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker exec 12461436e4cb1150a20d8fca13ef7691d66528a11864ab17600bb994a1248675 ls /migrations
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker logs --follow 12461436e4cb1150a20d8fca13ef7691d66528a11864ab17600bb994a1248675
DEBUG: Loading config file: /flyway/conf/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: /flyway/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: /flyway/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Using configuration:
DEBUG: flyway.locations -> filesystem:/migrations
Flyway Community Edition 7.5.3 by Redgate
DEBUG: Scanning for filesystem resources at '/migrations'
DEBUG: Scanning for resources in path: /migrations (/migrations)
DEBUG: Driver  : MySQL Connector/J mysql-connector-java-8.0.20 (Revision: afc0a13cd3c5a0bf57eaa809ee0ee6df1fd5ac9b)
DEBUG: Validating migrations ...
Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.033s)
Current version of schema `****`: 1
Schema `****` is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Database/migrations` is different from `/Database/migrations`

my `$WORKSPACE` var is actually pointing to `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/...` so I needed to update the mount path to `$WORKSPACE/Database/migrations:/migrations` ‍♂️